# What is the key for, Doflamingo is holding in chapter 752?

Tags: one-piece

As far as I recall, the only locks mentioned during the [Dressrosa Arc](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Dressrosa_Arc) are:

- The lock to the [SMILE factory](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SMILE_Factory)
- The lock of Law's handcuffs

Though, in **chapter 747** Doflamingo destroys the key to the factory.

[image: enter image description here!]

And in **chapter 750**, we can see Viola holding the key to Law's handcuffs.

[image: enter image description here!]

So what is the key, Doflamingo is holding in **chapter 752**, for?

[image: enter image description here!]

Comment: if you are satisfied, please mark one as right answer

Answer (score 2):

I think as far as we know, you can't tell for sure if it's one of these two possibilities.

But if I compare the key to the SMILE Factory with the last one you can't see anything similar. So I think it's **not another key to the Factory.**

[image]
[image]

Even though the other is much smaller on the picture, if you zoom in, you can see that the **key for Law's chain is round.** On the other side **Doflamingo's key has the shape of a heart.**

Another point is, that the **left one has a little hook...**

[image]
[image]

So I think this is just speculation, but I think even if it's one of these two options it would be the key to Law's chain.

In my opinion, it's a key to something new, maybe even more important.

Comment: If you look carefully Viola has a C-shaped key, while Doflamingo has en E-shaped key, so I doubt it would be a second key to Law's handcuffs. I guess we have to wait for the next chapters to find out. Too bad we're on a hiatus again ):

Comment: jap it's too bad... :/ Hope you liked my answer

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a month ago you asked this, but it hasn't really been made clear in the manga yet, sort of, so I'll drop my opinion. I think it's just another key to Law's handcuffs, because Doflamingo said he had something to deliver, but wasn't able to accomplish the job. Seems pretty obvious to me he's referring to the key he's holding in the next panel.
I don't think he just went there to kill them, he even said so himself, he came to "save" them. Also it's just logical for him or at least his 'family' to hold on to a key for the cuffs, seeing as Law was his prisoner and Doflamingo's got personal business with him. Even if that means there is more than one key.

On the other hand.. It being heart shaped and all, and the whole heart theme regarding Corazon.. And although he wanted to bring Law the key it doesn't really have to be for his cuffs.. I do think so but you're right. Maybe it does have another purpose. xD If there is any more meaning to that key I think we'll find out when they finally face each other again, probably the next chapter! ^^

Comment: I dont think they were for the cuffs since the key viola was holding was C-shaped, while Doffy's key was E shaped so it wouldnt fit. In retrospect it might be related to corazon as u said or it might be the key to the tontatta princess.